# Specifying an array's length in its type signature

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples

How do I specify an `Array'`s length in its type signature in TypeScript?

```
declare const a: Array<any>[20]; // wishful syntax
...
foo(a[10]); // fine
foo(a[100]); // type error: index is out of bounds
```

Comment: Related: [TypeScript: how to declare array of fixed size for type checking at Compile Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441408/typescript-how-to-declare-array-of-fixed-size-for-type-checking-at-compile-time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days, a viable alternative, at least for small arrays is the [*tuple*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) type:

```
declare const t: [boolean, number];
...
t[1] = 5; // fine
t[100] = foo; // error 2493: Tuple type '[boolean, number]' of length '2' has no element at index '100'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't, as arrays are not fixed length. Overindexing an array will not cause a compile time error.

This comes from the fact that arrays in JavaScript are really just special objects, with stricter defined property names and an extra `length` property. TypeScript only change one aspect of arrays: they can only contain a single type of elements.

Comment: Ok thanks. It could equally enforce bounds at compile time although things like `a[x]` are of course an easy way around that. Then at runtime Arrays can be any length and contain anything, anyway.