# TypeScript: how to declare array of fixed size for type checking at Compile Time

Tags: javascript, typescript, typechecking

**Update**: These checks are meant for **compile time**, not at **runtime**. In my example, the failed cases are all caught at compile time, and I'm expecting similar behaviour for the other **should-fail** cases.

Suppose I'm writing a table-like class where I want all members of the class to be arrays of the same length, something like:

```
class MyClass {
  tableHead:  string[3]; // expect to be a 3 element array of strings
  tableCells: number[3]; // expect to be a 3 element array of numbers
}
```

The closest solution I've found so far is:

```
class MyClass {
  tableHead:  [string, string, string];
  tableCells: [number, number, number];
}

let bar = new MyClass();
bar.tableHead = ['a', 'b', 'c']; // pass
bar.tableHead = ['a', 'b'];      // fail
bar.tableHead = ['a', 'b', 1];   // fail

// BUT these also pass, which are expected to fail at compile time
bar.tableHead = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']; // pass
bar.push('d'); // pass
bar.push('e'); // pass
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: You should wrap your member data in access functions. These can then check the number of arguments and/or length of data being asked to be added to your arrays.

Comment: You mean `getter` and `setter` ?

Comment: yes. make them private and provide methods to control what is being pushed or removed from your list. Then you would have total control on it

Comment: @iberbeu if I understand correctly, this provides checking at **runtime**, right? what about **compile time**? Like the way in C/C++.

Comment: Not currently possible, but there is a proposal: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6229

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - Fixed length Array<length> type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139763/typescript-fixed-length-arraylength-type)

Answer (score 16):

Update 2: From version 3.4, what the OP asked for is now fully possible with a succinct syntax ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20tableHead%3A%20readonly%20%5Bstring%2C%20string%2C%20string%5D%0D%0A%20%20tableCells%3A%20readonly%20%5Bnumber%2C%20number%2C%20number%5D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20bar%20%3D%20new%20MyClass()%3B%0D%0Abar.tableHead%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20pass%0D%0Abar.tableHead%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%5D%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20fail%20as%20expected%0D%0Abar.tableHead%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%201%5D%3B%20%20%20%2F%2F%20fail%20as%20expected%3B%0D%0Abar.tableHead%20%3D%20%5B'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%2C%20'd'%2C%20'e'%5D%3B%20%2F%2F%20fail%20as%20expected%0D%0Abar.push('d')%3B%20%2F%2F%20fail%20as%20expected%0D%0Abar.push('e')%3B%20%2F%2F%20fail%20as%20expected)):

```js
class MyClass {
  tableHead: readonly [string, string, string]
  tableCells: readonly [number, number, number]
}
```

Update 1: From version 2.7, TypeScript can now [distinguish between lists of different sizes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#fixed-length-tuples).

I don't think it's possible to type-check the length of a tuple. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5259#issuecomment-163056358)'s the opinion of TypeScript's author on this subject.

I'd argue that what you're asking for is not necessary. Suppose you define this type

```
type StringTriplet = [string, string, string]
```

and define a variable of that type:

```
const a: StringTriplet = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

You can't get more variables out of that triplet e.g.

```
const [one, two, three, four] = a;
```

will give an error whereas this doesn't as expected:

```
const [one, two, three] = a;
```

The only situation where I think the lack of ability to constrain the length becomes a problem is e.g. when you `map` over the triplet

```
const result = a.map(/* some pure function */)
```

and expect that `result` have 3 elements when in fact it can have more than 3. However, in this case, you are treating `a` as a collection instead of a tuple anyway so that's not a correct use case for the tuple syntax.

Comment: Good answer. I like that you included Hejlsberg's comment, helps to understand the background.

Answer (score 8):

From [Typescript: Can I define an n-length tuple type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489261/typescript-can-i-define-an-n-length-tuple-type), programmatically, with dynamic length:

```
type Tuple<TItem, TLength extends number> = [TItem, ...TItem[]] & { length: TLength };

type Tuple9<T> = Tuple<T, 9>;
```

Comment: what if this hardcoded 9 would need to be dynamic. In other words, given 2 tuples, i want a 2nd tuple to be as long as the first one.

Comment: from types point fo view, I think this is the most dynamic it can be. Maybe you are overcomplicating it and just need old array type:  MyThing[] ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example of a class to control the length of its internal array. It isn't fool-proof (when getting/setting you may want to consider whether you are shallow/deep cloning etc:

https://jsfiddle.net/904d9jhc/

```
class ControlledArray {

  constructor(num) {
    this.a = Array(num).fill(0); // Creates new array and fills it with zeros
  }

  set(arr) {
    if (!(arr instanceof Array) || arr.length != this.a.length) {
      return false;
    }
    this.a = arr.slice();
    return true;
  }

  get() {
    return this.a.slice();
  }

}

$( document ).ready(function($) {

  var m = new ControlledArray(3);

  alert(m.set('vera')); // fail
  alert(m.set(['vera', 'chuck', 'dave'])); // pass

  alert(m.get()); // gets copy of controlled array

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as you can see in the discussion under the question, I was intended to perform this check at **compile time**, not run time. I'm updating the question to avoid future confusions.