# Typescript: Can I define an n-length tuple type?

Tags: typescript

I am creating a shogi game board using Typescript. A shogi board has 9 ranks and files.

I'd like to assert a 9x9 multidimensional array as a type to ensure both the size and contents of the array.

Currently I am creating my 9x9 board type this way:

```
type Board9x9<P> = [
  [P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P],
  [P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P],
  [P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P],
  [P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P],
  [P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P],
  [P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P],
  [P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P],
  [P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P],
  [P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P]
];

interface IShogiBoardInternalState {
    board: Board9x9<IShogiPiece>;
    playerName: string;
    isYourTurn: boolean;
}
```

Question: Is there a less tedious, more generic way to define this tuple type which I have called `Board9x9<P>`?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

***Update***:

With [Recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002) (added in TypeScript 4.1.0) it is possible to:

```
type Tuple<T, N extends number> = N extends N ? number extends N ? T[] : _TupleOf<T, N, []> : never;
type _TupleOf<T, N extends number, R extends unknown[]> = R['length'] extends N ? R : _TupleOf<T, N, [T, ...R]>;

type Tuple9<T> = Tuple<T, 9>;
type Board9x9<P> = Tuple9<Tuple9<P>>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAPDANFAclCAPYCAOwBMBnKIuAWwCMIAnAPigF5tcDjyOB+SmvQadCpCjn4wA2gF0oALigB9eEggB5AGZpMWTLJaKiEAG6MA3AChQkZauRadHfKJ5U6jTACUR3CnCIAayIAewB3IgM2KC8pAHJkIgBzYAALOLkXPz4YhTsEB20MbH1igDoKrxkmK2twaHsIAE40FnZGpyaautsAIRCAQwYSJrwWgAU22ALmtBmJpm7LEggAY0Qh6FWQojJgKFpB4cV+oZGxlHchJcOzqQB2GQe5AHoXqHUAaUtLW+GpACMAKejygbygqQGFFCuGQ1GI+wG+wAlqR8FA4kC4r8jiRnoDgWD3pDoSFYRB4URESi0XgMVigA)

---

---

*Original answer*:

Typescript 3 introduces [rest elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types)

> The last element of a tuple type can be a rest element of the form ...X, where X is an array type

To restrict the length of a tuple we can use intersection with `{ length: N }`

```
type Tuple<TItem, TLength extends number> = [TItem, ...TItem[]] & { length: TLength };

type Tuple9<T> = Tuple<T, 9>;
type Board9x9<P> = Tuple9<Tuple9<P>>;
```

This works when variable of `Tuple` type is being initialized:

```
const t: Tuple<number, 1> = [1, 1] // error: 'length' incompatible.
```

**A caveat here**, typescript won't warn you if you'll try to access non element at index out of tuple range:

```
declare const customTuple: Tuple<number, 1>;
customTuple[10] // no error here unfortunately

declare const builtinTuple: [number];
builtinTuple[10] // error: has no element at index '10'
```

There's a [suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223) to add a generic way to specify length of a tuple type.

Comment: why `N extends N` in your example? Isn't it always true?

Comment: @trias you're right, this is not related to the question, but this triggers distribution over union and allows things like: `type VarLength = Tuple<number, 0 | 2 | 4>;` which results in `[] | [number, number] | [number, number, number, number]`

Comment: If union support is not needed, it could be just `type Tuple<T, N extends number, R extends unknown[] = []> = R['length'] extends N ? R : Tuple<T, N, [T, ...R]>;`

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/68216613/57611 which uses a similar recursive `Tuple` definition, but offers a solution to the invalid index problem. As one might expect, though, it has its own issues (can't extend the resulting class easily).

Comment: @ErikE The latest solution checks indexes properly

Comment: @AlekseyL. Ah... I must have missed something, Was reading the part saying indexes were not checked properly.

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks for this! It's pretty neat :)
Do you have any idea whether it could be possible at all to make this work? https://shorturl.at/krBP7

Comment: @ccjmne sorry, was away for a while. The link is no longer valid, could you recreate if still relevant?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Woops, sorry I missed your reply as well... I'm pretty sure what I want is legitimately impossible right now, but if you'd wanna take a look at it, I'd be very grateful! Here's what I'd like to do with my Tuples :) https://shorturl.at/kyCZ8

Comment: @ccjmne the link is dead again 

Comment: @AlekseyL. Ah! This is embarrassing I'll message in you in a chat room :)

Comment: This is amazing! With this Tuple type, you can create type guards for `Array.prototype.length` checks!

Comment: Is there anyway we could make the length part also variable size. what I mean is can I create a 
```typescript
const a: number = 5;
const tuple: Tuple<number, a> = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Comment: @AhmetK yes it is possible: `const a = 5; const tuple: Tuple<number, typeof a> = [1,2,3,4,5];`

Comment: I wonder why you need `N extends N ? ... : never`. the type within seems to work alone.

Comment: @Qwerty see first comments

Comment: Okay, that is interesting. Why does it work like that? Is it a consequence or a design, that conditional types are distributive? Was it easier to resolve each of the union members separately than try to go into the condition branches?

Comment: @Qwerty That's by design in typescript _When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type_ https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types

Answer (score 26):

One quick simplification would be to create a `Tuple9` type, that can be used to create the first level as well as the second level of the matrix:

```
type Tuple9<T> = [T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T]
type Board9x9<P> = Tuple9<Tuple9<P>>
```

Comment: That is pretty darn slick, but still could get ugly if I wanted to create a `Tuple36<T>` for a Taikyoku shogi board. xD. Still, your strategy is a significant code shrinkage compared to my strategy. Thank you!

Comment: It is true that this method can be more verbose than Aleksey's method. However, when I use Aleksey's method, the TS compiler lets me access indices that are out of bounds whereas the method in this answer prevents it. E.g. if I declare `const q: Board9x9<number> = ...` then with Aleksey's method `q[100][100]` compiles fine but with the code in this answer the compiler *correctly reports* a problem with the indices.

Comment: Just adding this here for completeness, you can now specify a tuple of length N as follows:
`type Tuple<T, N extends number, A extends any[] = []> = A extends { length: N } ? A : Tuple<T, N, [...A, T]>;`

Comment: cool, sometimes, simple is the best.

Answer (score 6):

You can make an arbitrary NxN board with the help of a Tuple type alias:

```
type Tuple<T, N extends number, A extends any[] = []> = A extends { length: N } ? A : Tuple<T, N, [...A, T]>;
```

So in your case you'd do something like:

```
type Tuple<T, N extends number, A extends any[] = []> = A extends { length: N } ? A : Tuple<T, N, [...A, T]>;

type Board9x9<P> = Tuple<Tuple<P, 9>, 9>;
```

Comment: Oh wow, this solution is much simpler than the accepted one.

Comment: @Qwerty They are actually the same. The accepted one is only that long because of the extra fluff and QoL. The `_TupleOf` type is the actual heavylifting. `TupleOf` only exists so you can't accidentally pass the 3rd type parameter. Then there's also validating if `N` is a number literal type in `TupleOf`. If you compare just `_TupleOf` to this answer's `Tuple` type then you will see it's exactly the same idea.

Answer (score 4):

```
type PushFront<TailT extends any[], FrontT> = (
  ((front : FrontT, ...rest : TailT) => any) extends ((...tuple : infer TupleT) => any) ?
  TupleT :
  never
)

type Tuple<ElementT, LengthT extends number, OutputT extends any[] = []> = {
  0 : OutputT,
  1 : Tuple<ElementT, LengthT, PushFront<OutputT, ElementT>>
}[
  OutputT["length"] extends LengthT ?
  0 :
  1
]

//type t3 = [string, string, string]
type t3 = Tuple<string, 3>
//type length = 0 | 3 | 1 | 2
type length = Partial<Tuple<any, 3>>['length']
```

[Add a generic way to specify length of a tuple type #issuecomment-513116547](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223#issuecomment-513116547)

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I did it in three steps

- Initialize tuple with an empty *<del>array</del>* **tuple** of the value type
- If the length of the tuple equals the desired length, return the tuple
- Otherwise, recursively add value type to the tuple

```js
type Tuple<V, N extends number, T extends V[] = []> =
    N extends T['length'] ? T : Tuple<V, N, [...T, V]>;
```

Usage:

```js
type String3 = Tuple<string, 3>; // [string, string, string]
type String3Number = [...String3, number]; // [string, string, string, number]
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in one line.

```
type Tuple<T, N, R extends T[] = []> = R['length'] extends N ? R : Tuple<T, N, [...R, T]>;
```

Usage:

```
Tuple<MyType, 100>;
```

Answer (score 0):

A thought for the common use case (like in this question) where the type you are trying to create should not have unsafe array methods that will mutate the underlying array (like `push`, `pop`, etc.):

```js
const board: Tuple<string, 4> = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
board.pop()
const fourthElement: string = board[3]; // No TS error
fourthElement.toUpperCase() // Errors when run, but no TS error
```

Instead of using a tuple, consider using an index signature restricted to only certain indices:

```js
// type BoardIndicies = 0 | 3 | 1 | 2
type BoardIndicies = Partial<Tuple<never, 3>>['length']

const board: Record<BoardIndicies, string> = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
board.pop() // ERROR: Property 'pop' does not exist on type 'Record<0 | 3 | 1 | 2, string>'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the accepted solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/52490977/1712683

You can handle the case to restrict people from updating the array by removing these types from the default types that are inherited from Array.prototype

```
type Exclude = 'push' | 'pop' | 'splice'
type Tuple<T, L extends number> = Omit<T[], Exclude> & {length: L}

type Board9x9<P> = Tuple<Tuple<P, 9>, 9>
```