# Is there any way to trigger a typescript compiler error in the code

Tags: typescript

I would like to check if an array has a specific length.
If the array length exceeds the limit, I would like to raise an error (or warning) when running the compiler.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript has what's called [Tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), which are essentially fixed-length arrays. You can't specify the length programmatically, but if your max length is low enough, what you can do is use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) (symbol `|`) to add together tuples of different lengths, until your wanted maximum.

Here's an example of how you could do it :

```
type maxThree = [] | [any] | [any, any] | [any, any, any]; // Any array of three or less elements

let arrayOk: maxThree = [1];
let arrayStillOk: maxThree = [1, 2];
let arrayTooLong: maxThree = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // <- Compilation error
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAtghgDwCoAsBOFoF4oG0C6UAPnnAHYiEm7kgA0UtVpFDtbF+A3FAPS9QAghUZo0cEFAD2AMyjB0maWigAbCAGcNUCOpgQywDQChj64KPEgA8gGsAXLESoM2PAEZuZiBbhiJAMrAAJaqqnaO8MiKbrjuDABMXuaWEkhSUgAyUmQA5pHOMVA4cYkMAMwMACzcfAIAPAC0UADCUjBgoXAhOTpiUmhAA)

Edit : After some research, it is *possible* to define a Tuple's length programmatically, although it's quite hacky and not completely type-safe. Still, this might interest you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52490977/1841827

Comment: Great! Thanks for that.