# How to check array length in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

case 1

```
 type ArrayEqualLength<T,?> = [T]
 const a: ArrayEqualLength<number,1> = [1,1] // x
 const a: ArrayEqualLength<number,1> = [1] // o
 const a: ArrayEqualLength<number,2> = [1,1] // o
```

case 2 GreaterThan

```
 type ArrayGreaterThanLength<T,?> = [T]
 const a: ArrayGreaterThanLength<number,2> = [1,1] // x
 const a: ArrayGreaterThanLength<number,2> = [1] // x
 const a: ArrayGreaterThanLength<number,2> = [1,1,1] // o
```

I want to check array length in typescript!

I can't find it when I search. Help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This might help with your first case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52490977/12414867

For example:

```
type TupleEq<TItem, TLength extends number> = [TItem, ...TItem[]] & { length: TLength };
const a: TupleEq<number, 4> = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

As for the second case, I'm not sure if it's possible in TS :/

Answer (score 0):

use Object no Array

Exmaple:

```
type ARRAY<T,?> = {
    array:Array<T>
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).