# How to declare a tuple type of size N (to use for vector class)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a tuple type, that has a fixed size N, so I can do something like this:

```
let tuple: Tuple<string, 2> = ["a","b"]
```

where "number" is the type T, and "2" is the size N. Then I want to create a (mathematical) Vector class, that implements the tuple, and adds methods (e.g. vector addition), like this:

```
class Vector<N extends number> implements Tuple<number,N> {...}
```

I did find many solutions (for the implementation of the tuple type), but all had some problems. The simplest solution I found ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139763/how-to-declare-a-fixed-length-array-in-typescript)) was using an interface like this:

```
interface Tuple<T, N extends number> extends ArrayLike<T> //or Array<T> {
   0: T
   length: N
}
```

But this implementation has the problem, that the compiler lets me access elements at invalid indices, like this:

```
let tuple: Tuple<number, 2> = [1,2]
tuple[4] //No compiler error, although the index is out of bounds.
```

The other implementation I could find ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489261/typescript-can-i-define-an-n-length-tuple-type)), is using recursive conditional types:

```
type Tuple<T, N extends number> = N extends N ? number extends N ? T[] : _TupleOf<T, N, []> : never;
type _TupleOf<T, N extends number, R extends unknown[]> = R['length'] extends N ? R : _TupleOf<T, N, [T, ...R]>;
```

This fixes the index issue, but I can't implement this type into my Vector class anymore, because it is a type union.
I get the following error:

> A class can only implement an object type or intersection of the object
> types with statically known members.ts(2422)

Is there any way to define a tuple type the way I want?

**Additional question:**
Is there a way to implement the tuple type without all the methods from the array class? I'm not sure yet if it would make sense for a Vector to have methods like filter, sort, and other unrelated methods. Especially methods that can mutate the size of the tuple would be very bad. I know that using ArrayLike instead of Array in the first implementation would at least achieve this. Omit would work too, but it's really annoying to specify every single method name manually.

Comment: The only affordance classes have for "dynamic" keys is to use an index signature; but as you saw, that means all (say) `number`-valued keys are allowed to have property values, not just the ones you intend.  As soon as you try to use conditional/generic/etc keys, you can't implement it in a class directly.  There are workarounds, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGny0m)... would you be interested in having that workaround as an answer?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your answer, this is basically the solution I was looking for (except for some small tweaks eventually). I'm not 100% sure wether I'm going to implement it this way, but it is definitely a good answer to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, the compiler will only allow an `interface` (or a `class` which brings an `interface` of the same name into scope) to have "statically known" keys.  So you can't extend or implement any type where the keys are deferred generics:

```
class Foo<K extends string> implements Record<K, string> { } // error!
// A class can only implement an object type or intersection of 
// object types with statically known members.
interface Bar<K extends string> extends Record<K, string> { } // error!
// An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of 
// object types with statically known members.
```

For your `Vector<N>` type, you want there to be numeric (or numeric-like) keys from `0` to one less than `N`.  Since `N` is generic in the definition of `Vector<N>`, that means the exact set of keys is not statically known (e.g., is `6` a key?  You won't know until you construct an instance), so you can't make `Vector<N>` a `class` or an `interface`.

If you allow *every* `number`-valued key to exist, you can use a statically-known numeric [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  But you specifically don't want to allow properties at keys of `N` or larger (or `-1` or `Math.PI`, etc).  So let's forget about using an index signature.

---

A workaround you can use here is to describe the types of `Vector<N>` instances as a `type` alias and not as an `interface` or `class`.  You can declare that there is a value named `Vector` whose type has a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) producing `Vector<N>` instances.

Then you can make something that works the way you want at runtime, but whose types are not exactly what you want.  For example, you can make a `class _Vector { ... }` with an index signature and all the functionality required for a `Vector<N>`.

And finally, you can assign `_Vector` to the variable named `Vector`, and [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the former has the type of the latter.  It's basically sidestepping the requirement for statically known keys.

Let's do that in stages:

---

**Describe the types:**

Starting with your [recursive conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) definition for a tuple of length `N`:

```
type Tuple<T, N extends number> = N extends N ? number extends N ? 
  T[] : { length: N } & _TupleOf<T, N, []> : never;
type _TupleOf<T, N extends number, R extends unknown[]> = 
  R['length'] extends N ? R : _TupleOf<T, N, [T, ...R]>;
```

We'll describe `Vector<N>` as a type with all the numeric-like keys of `Tuple<number, N>`, as well as a `length` of `N`, and any `Vector`-specific methods or properties you want your class to have:

```
type Vector<N extends number> =
  Omit<Tuple<number, N>, keyof any[]> &
  {
    length: N;
    vectorMethod(): void;
  };
```

And the constructor can be described like this:

```
interface VectorConstructor {
  new <N extends number>(...init: Tuple<number, N>): Vector<N>;
}
```

**Implement a class that works at runtime:**

We'll just use an index signature:

```
class _Vector {
  [k: number]: number | undefined;
  length: number;
  constructor(...init: number[]) {
    this.length = init.length;
    for (const [i, v] of init.entries()) {
      this[i] = v;
    }
  }
  vectorMethod() {
    console.log("something here");
  }
}
```

**Assert that the implemented class constructs the desired instance type:**

```
const Vector = _Vector as VectorConstructor;
```

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const v = new Vector(0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25); // Vector<6>
/* v: {
    length: 6;
    0: number;
    1: number;
    2: number;
    3: number;
    4: number;
    5: number;
    vectorMethod: () => void;
} */

v[3]++; // okay
v.vectorMethod();
v[10]; // error
```

Looks good.  The value `v` is of type `Vector<6>`, which has the six numeric indices we want, a `length` property of type `6`, and the `vectorMethod()` we added.  And so it behaves as desired.

---

There are caveats here, of course.  The obvious one is that the compiler might not catch errors in your implementation, because you are using a type assertion.  So you need to take care.  A less obvious one is that you are sweeping the problem of statically-known keys under the rug.  If someone comes along later and tries to extend or implement your new class type, they will get the same error you got originally:

```
class Oops<N extends number> extends Vector<N> { } // error!
/* Base constructor return type 'Vector<N>' is not an object type
  or intersection of object types with statically known members. */
```

So if you want a class hierarchy, you     will need to keep using the above trick, which could get tedious:

```
class _Sigh extends _Vector {
  anotherMethod() {

  }
}
type Sigh<N extends number> = Vector<N> & { anotherMethod(): void };
interface SighConstructor { new <N extends number>(...init: Tuple<number, N>): Sigh<N>; }
const Sigh = _Sigh as SighConstructor;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4&ssl=44&ssc=15&pln=43&pc=15#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8BpaBTAHgF3QOwBMYJsAnASzwHMA+acgWwAcR0H9sYAldYeUgqgA00EhWp0A3tAC+0APTyMpUvwCEAWABQi6AEFooSDGBg80eHhABPes1bs82aGYsAjAFa9n2a03QWpPRO6KQQ3uSWFgBm0Nq68J7e0L7+MADu5NgAFqLYYNjkpiA20ADWePDp5uwMbqEQAHTalLik0WDAAQBCYKSoGDj4RHnitIO4hNy8-IIoImKU49JyuqGqpJo6SnrmraEdXYaulqVYkwQu5olewD5+AfzBbeF3kdex8Uo3yanoGVlciQCkUwCVbBUqjU2PUws0tNovtACP9gBR6sj-uRSOhLn8INo-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-xJyefYwgiKJHJ+M38WgEigUI0FwXKSpqmgWpYSaaBMa58B6O1ABlcgqFyIW+vmjSriNgraZipGvNClCHX8aBw8jwXaz-YV2Tmu9qzoLVpDMBPQmi+HYoPI9LhkYtrcOAJs+yYa5MiyXZtzi5GRFhSQLwMCSU7JBuxghU25L4mwsmtv9LDiPckgLPl470a71tIA)

Comment: Again, thank you for the very detailed explanation! It's a shame that this workaround is apparently the only solution to my problem... but at least it works as intended.