# TypeScript does no type checking When the array is empty

Tags: typescript

When the array is empty, TS does no type checking

My code here

```js
type List = { name: string }[]

const l: List = []

// error
l[0].name
```

Is there any way to make TS check？How do I make TS check work?

Comment: TS doesn't know how many things you have in the array at runtime. Yes, it could *here*, but imagine the code was `const l: List = getSomeListUsingUser(input);`  - then TS *cannot* know how many items the list contains. It can similarly not know if any particular place is empty, .e.g, `[a, b, , d]` will have `length = 4` however `l[2]` doesn't exist.

Comment: Please consider [noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) in `compilerOptions` in your `tsconfig.json`.

After this you will start getting TS errors like `Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)` on such statements.

```
type List = { name: string }[]

const l: List = []

l[0].name // <-- error

l[0]?.name // <-- no error (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2FAvFA3lAdgQwLYQBcUSATnFgOZQC+A2gLoBQTAxgPZZJQA2x83NIxY86ABgYA6XARHiGAfmn4ITIA)

Note that `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` option doesn't check the length of your array; it basically keeps reminding you that the index you are trying to access may not exist.

---

If your array (and its elements) are meant to be read only, you can also use const assertion:

```
const l = [{ name: 'foo' }] as const

l[0].name // no error
l[1] // error: Tuple type 'readonly [{ readonly name: "foo"; }]' of length '1' has no element at index '1'.(2493)
```

---

If you just want your array length to be fixed but the elements mutable, then in TS4.1 and above you can do this:

```
// based on - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52490977

type _TupleOf<T, N extends number, R extends unknown[]> = R['length'] extends N ? Readonly<R> : _TupleOf<T, N, [T, ...R]>
type Tuple<T, N extends number> = N extends N ? (number extends N ? T[] : _TupleOf<T, N, []>) : never

type List = Tuple<{ name: string }, 1>

const l: List = [{ name: 'foo' }]

l[0].name // no error
l[1] // error: Tuple type 'readonly [{ name: string; }]' of length '1' has no element at index '1'.(2493)
```