# Explanation of " R['length'] extends N " syntax in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, tuples

new to TypeScript, was searching for a way to define a fixed size array and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52490977/157247):

```typescript
type Tuple<T, N extends number> = N extends N ? number extends N ? T[] : _TupleOf<T, N, []> : never;
type _TupleOf<T, N extends number, R extends unknown[]> = R['length'] extends N ? R : _TupleOf<T, N, [T, ...R]>;

type Tuple9<T> = Tuple<T, 9>;
type Board9x9<P> = Tuple9<Tuple9<P>>;
```

...which obtains the desired result using recursive conditional types.
I was trying to understand the syntax that is being used, and I couldn't really understand what is happening behind the scenes particularly in this point: `R['length'] extends N`.

I understood that it checks if the array is of the desired length and if not it'll recursively call `_TupleOf` with an extra element until that condition becomes true. but why is that happening?
I searched for answers but couldn't really find anything useful.

Does `R['length']` return the actual length as a number if it is applied to a type? And why `extends` seems to behaves like a `==` operator in this case?

I've also tried double-checking if it behaves as i understood in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgTnKBeKBtAzsOBLAdgcwBopMcCBdAKEtEigCNlYFUByAGwgOAAtXyoEAB7AuAE3RQAzFAD8UAES1oMBQC5FyhgoDcNcNADGTeHDadufAcNG4JUAExzNB2Opd16u6pSA) (you can hover over `b` and `c` to check the types) and it seems it does, still can't understand why tho.

Any link or explanation? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because:

1. The type of the `length` property of a tuple is a *literal* numeric type equal to the number of elements in the tuple. So not just a `number`, but a *specific* number (like `42`).
2. Numeric literal types extend `number`. *(Hmmm... I'm not sure why I mentioned this, but it's in the examples below so I'll keep it.)*
3. A numeric literal type only "extends" (is the same as or a subtype of) itself.

```typescript
type TwoThings = [string, string];
type TwoThingsLength = TwoThings["length"];
//   ^? −−− type TwoThingsLength = 2

type IsNumber<T> = T extends number ? true : false;
type A = IsNumber<27>;
//   ^? −−− type A = true
type B = IsNumber<"example">;
//   ^? −−− type B = false

type IsThisNumber<T, Num> = T extends Num ? true : false;
type C = IsThisNumber<27, 27>;
//   ^? −−− type C = true
type D = IsThisNumber<27, 42>;
//   ^? −−− type D = false

// Which leads us to
type E = IsThisNumber<TwoThingsLength, 2>; // true, they're the same literal number
//   ^? −−− type E = true
type F = IsThisNumber<TwoThingsLength, 3>; // false, they aren't
//   ^? −−− type F = false
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg7gexgCwJYDsDmBnKBeKAbW2ACcNMAaKE8rAXQG4BYAKFElkRQuwBkIWYMnxckaLNkIAiADaDMw6UzYB6VVE0A9APxs2HaAElsAOQCuAWwBGEUgB4YAPlEwoEAB7BBAE1zorW1IoHSgyc2gALigAMwBDWWwIFnZwaABBURMLGzt7ACYAdicU9U0oXQM0qAAhLLNAvOlPOMsweWkStQ1tPVYqzhMeBtyHGGoclwI3T290PygckLDSCKho+MTkgegAYXrhnKCCwuoirtYy3p2oABEDtBHjouoAFnyLq4q+7qgAdTQAGMRPI4gtzLhgAgbgBRB6oJ55eDiXgCITIM6fHrfG4AMXhiLG3AkODRigxUAAzFjyrogA)

So `R['length'] extends N ? R : _TupleOf<T, N, [T, ...R]>` works by:

- If `R['length']` is the same as the target length `N`, evaluate to the `R` type itself
- If not, create a new tuple type which has element `T` plus all of the previous elements (`...R`) — e.g., add one — and recurse

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing, thank you very much!