How to type number of returned elements based on parameter
I would like to know how to type the returned values of this function
async function createItems(nb = 10): Promise<???> {

  const items: Item[] = await Promise.all(
    Array.from({ length: nb }, (_, idx) => createItem(idx + 1))
  ); // create `nb` items


  return items.reduce(
    (acc, item, idx) => {
      const num = String(idx + 1).padStart(2, '0');

      acc[`item${num}`] = item;

      return acc;
    },
    {},
  );

}

usage :
const { item01, item02, item03 } = await createItems(3);


Why don't you return an array? Then the solution is e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52489261/3001761

@jonrsharpe Beacause I want to be able to do this const { item06 } = await createItems(10);instead of const [,,,,,item06] = await createItems(10);

If you're going to throw away 90% of your created items anyway, why create them at all? Seems weird. I'd do const item06 = createItem(6) in that case.

I asked a question about a specific case and provided a function as an example. I thought people on SO would help me and give me the answer I asked for and not something else that would just fit their point of view. Thanks for your time anyway.

Since the answer obviously isn't very straightforward—otherwise you'da probably already figured it out yourself—it's always useful to prod whether that's really what you need and whether some seemingly more conventional solutions mightn't suffice.

@deceze I understand what you mean. I do know how to code, I just don't know Typescript (so I wouldn't have figured it out myself) and I was hoping I could ask something simple (so I thougth) without having to explain my entire code base for you to understand.

createItem() and type Item are not provided ?

What kind of type hint are you hoping for? It's probably impossible to type it such that any tool understands that createItems(3) will return an object with exactly the properties item01, item02, item03. At best you can type hint it as "returns object with some properties". Is that good enough?

It doesn't motivate to solve the problem if its incomplete to begin with and one has to figure out problems that are not part of the problem. See my answer if I understood the question correctly?

@deceze Yes "It's probably impossible" is a perfectly legit answer and I would have accepted it. For the record, I asked ChatGPT the question with no information other than my code and it gave me the answer without complaining that my code didn't make sense.

This question is very confusing as it is not quite clear what you want.
You could have asked: How can I create a union of keys from an index.
At least this is how I understand the question.
So here is a solution: (I assume the logic is not important.)
type Item = { id: number; value: string };

type CreateKeys<
  N extends number,
  Current extends unknown[] = []
> = Current['length'] extends N
  ? `item${Current['length']}`
  : `item${Current['length']}` | CreateKeys<N, [unknown, ...Current]>;

export async function createItems<C extends number = 10>(
  count: C = 10 as C
): Promise<Record<CreateKeys<C>, Item>> {
  return {} as any;
}

const result = await createItems(3); // =>  Record<"item0" | "item1" | "item2" | "item3", Item>

If you need the first index to be 1 just change the types.

The main problem is to create the returned object's keys, some string manipulations are needed, like padding:
Playground
type Item = {
  test: true
};

type LengthOfString<S extends string,  T extends string[] = []> = S extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ? LengthOfString<R, [...T, F]> : T['length'];
type PadStart<S extends string | number, N extends Number, P extends string> = LengthOfString<`${S}`> extends N ? S : PadStart<`${P}${S}`, N, P>;
type ItemKey<IS extends unknown[]> = `item${PadStart<IS['length'], 2, '0'>}`;
type ItemKeys<N extends Number, IS extends unknown[] = [unknown]> = IS['length'] extends N ? ItemKey<IS> : ItemKey<IS> | ItemKeys<N, [unknown, ...IS]>;

async function createItems<N extends number = 10>(nb: N | 10 = 10): Promise<Record<ItemKeys<N>, Item>> {
  return {} as any;
}

const items = createItems(); // const items: Promise<Record<"item01" | "item02" | "item03" | "item04" | "item05" | "item06" | "item07" | "item08" | "item09" | "item10", Item>>
const items3 = createItems(3); // const items3: Promise<Record<"item01" | "item02" | "item03", Item>>


