# Why is the generic value N not inferred from arguments in this case?

Tags: typescript, generics

This question:

[TypeScript: Require that two arrays be the same length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206320/typescript-require-that-two-arrays-be-the-same-length)

Asks how to create a function that requires two arrays of the same length.

Here's my attempt at a solution.

```
type ArrayOfFixedLength<T extends any, N extends number> = readonly T[] & { length: N }; 

const a1: ArrayOfFixedLength<number, 2> = [1] as const; //expected error
const a2: ArrayOfFixedLength<number, 2> = [1, 2] as const; 


function myFunction<N extends number>(array1: ArrayOfFixedLength<any, N >, array2: ArrayOfFixedLength<any, N>) {
return true; 
}

myFunction<3>([1, 2, 3] as const, [2, 3, 4] as const); 
myFunction<2>([1, 2] as const, [1, 2, 3] as const); //expected error

// However, if you don't specify the array length, 
// It fails to error
myFunction([1, 2, 3] as const, [2, 3, 4] as const); 
myFunction([1, 2] as const, [1, 2, 3] as const); // error is expected, but there is none.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=30&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=1#code/FAguE8AcFMAIEEBOiCG4DyAzAYgSwB7QAmAMtAHYDmoAFgDwAqs0+oFRAzrCueADSwAcs1bsu5AK4BbAEbREAPlgBeWImgoiAe3IAbcLAYBtALqwAZLADesXRWo0AXENgBfANywQAYx0dQ3ACMzkioGDgExGRUtHSSsvICAExKqkaBZihcvuT+nsA5-txJIchoWHiEpPax8XKIyamw6cmZ2X6g+SDAmBLk3qC4OrBS4Nh9A0PkdMIsbOScsHXyCgAUKGXgwQibFZHVMfQ8-C4KAhthJTthe1XRDnTHAoIKAJTWwOqgEojksKCICTQfKubrAUbjfqDHR0ADMaxasCSAlhbVghVAAiMyNgsIEABY0RjXvkIRNodMUqtEUkiR0sYFkii6blQCSQAB6DmwAASWgA7tAAG6JWC4TCwcBaCSwbTkADkAQ4MG84oMtDgFzQthqNAEwC5sAAkgFMChcLouKAtMxkFpEOCxuSptTGUjmdx2qysTi8bBCZ70R0SV4yVCXTSWf4GUzcVG2e4QEA)

As noted, this code only gives the TypeScript error if you explicitly state the generic value `N` - the length of the arrray.

Why is TypeScript unable to infer the value N from the arguments passed into the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give a hint to the compiler to expect a tuple type.  Otherwise the compiler will widen an array literal like `[2, 3, 4]` to `number[]`.  The hint usually takes the form of including a tuple type in the type annotation or generic constraint; preferably a union of some tuple type that doesn't get in the way of what you're doing:

```
function myFunction<N extends number>(
    array1: ArrayOfFixedLength<any, N> | [never],
    array2: ArrayOfFixedLength<any, N & {}> | [never]) {
    return true;
}
```

The `| [never]` is a hint.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#27179](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179) and specifically [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990) for more information. I used `[never]` since I expect that you won't pass any arrays with a `never` value, so it won't matter in practice if `array1` accepts such an array.

Yes, it's ugly.  I've asked for an easier way in [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680), but I don't know if something like that will ever be implemented.

---

Also, note that for `array2` I've replaced `N` with `N & {}`.  If you don't do that, your function will not serve the purpose of constraining the two arrays to the same length; instead, `N` will just be inferred as the union of the lengths of the two arrays.  Ideally you want *only* `array1` to be used to *infer* `N`, and the `N` in `array2` should be "non-inferential".  There's an open GitHub issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731), asking for support for this.  The `& {}` is a [technique to lower the inference priority](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731), which suffices to only infer `N` from `array1` and not `array2`.

Let's see it work:

```
myFunction([1, 2, 3] as const, [2, 3, 4] as const); // okay
myFunction([1, 2] as const, [1, 2, 3] as const); // error
myFunction([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]); // okay
myFunction([1, 2], [1, 2, 3]); // error
```

Looks good to me.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAguE8AcFMAIEEBOiCG4DyAzAYgSwB7QAmAMtAHYDmoAFgDwAqs0+oFRAzrCueADSwAcs1bsu5AK4BbAEbREAPlgBeWImgoiAe3IAbcLAYBtALqwAZLADesXRWo0AXENgBfANwgAxjo6huAIzOSKgYOATEZFS0dJKy8gIATEqqRgFmKFw+5H6e2X7cicHIaFh4hKT2MXFyiEkpsGlJGVm+oJ7AsCCYEuReoLg6sFLg2L39g+R0wixs5JywNfIKABSdsBsoJeBBCNtlEZXR9Dz8QkoAPo3k0ABu8iZ865vbRXuhBxVRDnSnAsKWKyuS7XO4PACU1meamgoAkiHIsFAiAk0E8rhAIzGfQGOhWTVgiQEAGYWrB8qABEYibBiQIACxking9ywAD0bNgWgA1mhgFjxrjyPiAs1uK0cpTGqLCSSmW0WezOfJEFpEPzRoLJiKknKqTS6bBGYqOVzeeANdiJniCYlHtLdbSTCblcg1UA)

Comment: Ugh. More and more I'm realising that, while typescript probably can do everything you want, getting it to that is hard.