# Interface: Pass two array of specific length as prop

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like this

```
interface FooProps {
    cat: string[],
    kitten: number[],
}
```

Is there any way to tell TypeScript that `kitten` and `cat` must be the same length? Note, the length varies, depending on where the interface `FooProps` is used. But, whenever I use `FooPros`, the length of `cat` and `kitten` must be the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Require that two arrays be the same length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62206320/typescript-require-that-two-arrays-be-the-same-length)

Comment: Also made an edit based on @vera. suggestion to include the type checking for length comparison so you get intellisense too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
interface FooProps {
  cat: string[];
  kitten: number[];
}

// If cat and kitten are of fixed same length then
// the easiest way would be to define them as tupples

interface FooPropsAsTupple {
  cat: [string, string];
  kitten: [number, number];
}

const catsTupples: FooPropsAsTupple = {
  cat: ["", ""],
  kitten: [1, 2],
};

// however if they are dynamic, then you need to validate
// using a class (There are other ways too but this is easy)

class Felines<T extends string[], K extends number[]> implements FooProps {
  constructor(props: { cat: [...T]; kitten: K["length"] extends T["length"] ? [...K] : never }) {
    if (props.cat.length !== props.kitten.length) {
      throw new Error(`Cat and kitten must have the same length`);
    }
    const { cat, kitten } = props;
    this.cat = cat;
    this.kitten = kitten;
  }
  public cat!: string[];
  public kitten!: number[];
}

// Error: Cat and kitten must have the same length
new Felines({ cat: ["", "", ""], kitten: [1, 2] });
```

You may even combine both approach in order to get type completion but also actual safety by throwing error.

Comment: Why not just make it error at build time if we're going to use a class? https://tsplay.dev/w1E4Gw