# TypeScript array with arbitrary minimum length N, which can be large

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I want to create a `type` where an array has a minimum length of N. I have looked at this [TypeScript array with minimum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49910889/typescript-array-with-minimum-length) , but when N is large, I do not want to write out the type from 0 to N, e.g. :

```
type ArrayTwoOrMore<T> = {
    0: T
    1: T
    ...
    N: T
}
```

I was wondering whether there was a neater way of doing this?

Comment: If you are using a recent version of TS, the other answer there is better namely `type ArrayTwoOrMore<T> = [T, T, ...T[]]`, but you still need to spell out all members, no way to say greater than N

Comment: For info: [typescript-how-to-declare-array-of-fixed-size-for-type-checking-at-compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441408/typescript-how-to-declare-array-of-fixed-size-for-type-checking-at-compile-time/42448879)

Comment: In Typescript you can create types like this `type Pair<T, U> = [T, U]` and  `type Tripple<T> = [T, T, T]` I think @TitianCernicova-Dragomir answer is the best you can get with typescript in one line of code

Comment: not sure why I did not think of this yesterday, in 4.0 this will be easier. 10x @IAMTHEBEST for bringing the question back in my mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do arbitrary tuple size, but in 4.0 you will be able to create a type like `Typle5` or `Tuple10` and spread that multiple times to get to the desired type faster:

```
type Tuple5<T> = [T, T, T, T, T]
type Tuple10<T> = [...Tuple5<T>, ...Tuple5<T>]
type Tuple50<T> = [...Tuple10<T>, ...Tuple10<T>, ...Tuple10<T>, ...Tuple10<T>, ...Tuple10<T>]
type Tuple100<T> = [...Tuple50<T>, ...Tuple50<T>]

let a: Tuple100<number> = [] // Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 100
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-dev.20200623&ssl=6&ssc=80&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhArAHhgPigXigbRgBpYTjTYBdAWAChRJYFkBGABg2z3wDo-4kqTiT48BydFhr1w0cag5ZcBUfPbCoq5hHVYR-bbsz6xhxcc0HBR6Qzlnzy3lYnmT8lOel1kwKAEMALiZrNg4AOzgAWwAjCAAnLgJKKAB6VKgAZQB7OHiAY2gAC38AZyg2KAhkKIhw4AAKUoBKKBi4P2B-eIBzCD94iABHOABLQfL2NiA)

I would question the sanity of creating a tuple of size 100 though.

NOTE: 4.0 is still in beta should be released in August 2020